# Android Market - app update

Tags: android, google-play

I have a weird problem with my app and Android Market. I've uploaded my first app to the market with versionCode set to 1 and the versionName 1.0.0. Today I've uploded an update version which had tas versionCode set to 2 and the versionName set to 1.0.1. I then activated the new version. After a while the marked update the page of my app and the update showed up on my phone. When i check the update then instead of an "Update" button like for every other application there is an "Open" and "Uninstall" button.... I have no idea what the problem could be... Please help!

Answer (score 2):

There I've seen delays of up to 3 hours in the android market fully refreshing its servers.  Market App on your phone also caches (a reboot would sort this).

I've seen inconsistencies between search results, product listing page and the download page during the hours after an update. Even inconsistencies between 2 phones in the same room!

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the trying to update a developer version from eclipse which is signed with a different key to the one you used when publishing to the market.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is not the case. I removed the debug version and downloaded 1.0.0 from the market. I then pushed the exported 1.0.1 to the marked and now I'm facing the described problem.

Comment: I don't know if it's just me or are the other users experiancing the same problem.